# User authenticates on login page, but does not show as authenticated on redirected page

Tags: django-views

I've seen a lot of outdated posts mentioning render_to_response. From my understanding, redirect() should maintain the context.

Here's the code for my login view

```
def login(request):

    context = {}
    context['form'] = LoginForm
    context['loginFailure'] = False

    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['user']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                print('logged in on /login!')
                return redirect('/')
        else:            
            context['loginFailure'] = True
            print('Invalid login on /login!')
            return render(request,'q/login.html', context )    

    return render(request,'q/login.html', context )
```

It correctly prints to the terminal when I login with valid credentials.

On the index view, I have this code

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    print("index: Authenticated!")
else:
    print('index: Not authenticated...')
```

But every time I login successfully and /login/ prints a successful message, the index view tells me that I'm not authenticated. What do I need to do to maintain the context after a successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call django login also. [doc ref](https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/&ei=98jCSuO7&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=476&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1484852422&sig=AF9NedmRuDY_7GHjiJ8jsLMhlPWw7FxAFA#a-how-to-log-a-user-in)

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
if user is not None: 
    login(request, user)
    print('logged in on /login!') 
    return redirect('/')
```